# Spring security - Limiting access to my update profile page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using spring security in my application and ran into a problem. My application has an `Update Profile` page. I have added preAuthorized() with request mapping as

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping (value="/user/{uid}/profile/update", method = GET)
public String updateProfileView(@ModelAttribute("form") UserProfileForm form, @PathVariable ("uid") Integer userId, Model model){
```

It works fine, and `unauthenticated` user can not access this page.

But the issue is that `every Authenticated User can access this page`.

For example : User A logged in into application, he/she will be able to update every one's profile.

My CustomUserDetailService class is

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

@Resource
UserService userService;

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    com.analyst.future.domain.User user = userService.getUser(email);

    SimpleGrantedAuthority auth = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");

    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
    authorities.add(auth);

    User userDeatails = new User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), authorities);
    return userDeatails;

}

}
```

I don't think i can restrict it with `roles` as every authenticated user will have same roles.

Is there any way i can restrict Authenticated user to access only self `update profile` page.

Comment: On page load could you just check the current logged in user against the username being used to load the page, and display an error if they dont match?

Comment: yes, that is what i can do, but is there any solution provided by spring sercurity?

Comment: i do it in the same way, i check the requested username with the name of the principal.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I have the same question.

Answer (score 1):

I am no Spring Security expert, but try reading up on using Expression-Based Access - [Link here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

There is one tiny little line that matches what you want -

> For example, if you wanted a particular method to only allow access to a user whose username matched that of the contact, you could write
>
> ```
> @PreAuthorize("#contact.name == authentication.name")
> public void doSomething(Contact contact);
> ```

I think in your case it would be something like

```
@PreAuthorize("email == authentication.email")
```

This is method level though, so maybe not what you are looking for? Good news is that there is a way to use the logged in user and match it against the request user.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Since all previous answers talk about matching username (which is included in the principal object) but you need to match the userID, this needs a little more work. We first need to return a custom User object that extends `UserDetails`. Here is how you can do that:

#### Step 1: Make your 'User' model implement `UserDetails`

```
@Entity
public class UserAccount implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    private String email;
    private String password;

    // other fields and methods
}
```

You will also have to override some methods from `UserDetails`, which is easy to figure out.

#### Step 2: Make you User Service implement `UserDetailsService`

```
@Component
public class UserAccountService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        // todo
    }
}
```

#### Step 3: Return YOUR user model from the `loadUserByUsername` method

```
@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
    Optional<UserAccount>  userAccount = userAccountDao.findByEmail(username);

    if (!userAccount.isPresent()) {
        throw new MyException("User account not found for the given Username.", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return userAccount.get();
}
```

#### Step 4: Add the `@PreAuthorize` expression to your resource

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{userId}")
@PreAuthorize("#userId == authentication.principal.userId or hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
public UserAccount updateUserAccount(@PathVariable("userId") int userId,
                                         @RequestBody UserAccount userAccount) {
    return userAccountService.updateUserAccount(userId, userAccount);
}
```

Important things to notice above are:

- We can check if the userId is equal above, only because our custom `UserAccount` model has a userId. If we had returned a raw `UserDetail` (like `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`) object instead, it will not have any 'id' property to match with, so above will fail.
- Above `@PreAuthorize` annotation checks for 2 conditions. It allows the request ***if*** the user is the owner of the Account ***or*** if the user has ADMIN authority.